# In ggplot2 , how to align label x text in vertical

Tags: ggplot2, tidyverse

In ggplot2 , how to align label x in vertical ?  The wished result as attached image .

```
library(tidyverse)
category <- c("A B C","DF GC","S AA")
amount <- c(3,2,1)

plot_data <- data.frame(category,amount)

plot_data %>% ggplot(aes(x=category,y=amount))+geom_col()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
category <- c("A B C", "DF GC", "S AA")
amount <- c(3, 2, 1)

plot_data <- data.frame(category, amount)

plot_data %>%
  mutate(category = str_wrap(category, 1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(category, amount)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>